# trouble connecting via httpclient

Tags: php, android, http

Been having this issue for awhile now.. I'm trying to connect to a php script which echos the image location, and I'm trying to eventually display the picture on my app. However, I'm not even sure if I'm connecting to the php script.

"error in http connection, unknownhost error..."

thanks.

try {

```
            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();

            String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);
            Log.d("test", responseBody); 
           // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), responseBody, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

         // Loader image - will be shown before loading image
            int loader = R.drawable.icon;

            // Imageview to show
            ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

            // Image url
            String image_url = "http://www.xxx.php";
            String fullUrl = "http://www.xxx.php"+responseBody;
            test.setText(fullUrl);
            // ImageLoader class instance
            ImageLoader imgLoader = new ImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

            // whenever you want to load an image from url
            // call DisplayImage function
            // url - image url to load
            // loader - loader image, will be displayed before getting image
            // image - ImageView
            imgLoader.DisplayImage(fullUrl, loader, image);



        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
```

Comment: do you have internet permission in manifest file?

Answer (score 0):

Is it on the emulator??
If so try to add it the dns..

```
Window>Preferences>Android>Launch
Default emulator options: -dns-server 8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4
```